# why TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when calling function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [5,5,6,7,7,7]
b = set(a)
def test(lst):
    if lst in b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
print(test(a))  #this gives me error list unhashable  
print(test,a)   #how this is working
for i in  filter(test, a):
    print(i,end=" ")
```

output :  5 5 6 7 7 7

why print(test(a)) giving me error?

Comment: please disclose the output's

Comment: What is the purpose of the function `test`? `b` is a set of numbers, so it cannot contain `lst` which is a list, not a number.

Comment: what is your requirement/ expected output ?

Comment: I am not understanding how it is working.

Comment: I want to understand how function is calling and working

Comment: Are you asking how `filter` works? Note, `print(test,a)` doesn't call `test` if that's what you are asking. Also, why are you returning `1` and `0`?

Comment: yes my question is how print(test,a) is calling

Comment: without brackets can we call function and how

Comment: It **isn't** calling your function. That simply prints the `test` function object and `a`

Comment: then how filter works in my code

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `filter`? What, **exactly** do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let me tell you why `print(test, a)` is working first.

When you call `print(func)` without function call (or in other words, without doing `print(func())`, what you are actually doing is printing the functions object, which happens to return a `str` representation of the function that contains the location of the function in memory.

```py
def func():
    return "Hello World!"

print(func)      # >> <function func at 0x100858950>
print(func())    # >> Hello World!
print(func, "a") # >> <function func at 0x100858950> a
```

Now in regard to why you are receiving your error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`, this is due to the nature of a `set` and of a `list`. Notice the following will reproduce your exact error:

```py
foo = [1, 2, 3]
set = {4, 5}

print(foo in set)
```

Outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(foo in set)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This error is due to how `set()` works in Python. Notice the documentation for `set()` ([here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set)) states:

> Return a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from iterable. **The elements of a set must be hashable**. To represent sets of sets, the inner sets must be frozenset objects. If iterable is not specified, a new empty set is returned.

A "hashable" element, defined by Python's doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-hashable) states:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.

What is going on is that a Python's `list` object is not hashable due to its very nature -- no `__hash__()` functionality.

```py
class Foo:
    foo = 1

a = 1
b = Foo()
c = "Hello World!"
d = [1, 2, 3]
```

Outputs:

```py
1
280623165
-5794655848578721369
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(d.__hash__())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

In other words, `list`s are not hashable types in Python, and therefore you cannot check if they exist within a `set` since `set` will utilize the `__hash__()` functionality of objects to check if they exist within the set.

Comment: I can understand now.

Answer (score 0):

`print(test,a)` just printing function of `test` memory adress like `<function test at 0x10d02d1e0>` and list of `a`. Its the same thing like `print("abcd",212)` , So in this print , your test function doesnt run.

Your function is running in

```
print(test(a))
```

And you have some error here

Comment: It's not "printing the address", it's printing the string representation of the function object, which is the default object representation inherited from `object`, which happens to include a memory address

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you are checking whether list `a` is in the set `b` or not, here list `a` is a mutable object, you can't do like this. That's why it's throwing the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Read more about [in operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)

And `print(test, a)` is simply printing the `test` function object and the value of `a`

Try the code below,

```
a = [5,5,6,7,7,7]
b = set(a)
for i in filter(lambda x: x in b, a):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Output

```
5 5 6 7 7 7
```

Comment: @paraspatel Updated, hope you can understand it.

Comment: @paraspatel Read this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in